# "For such requests/questions" or "In such requests/questions"?

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

> **In/for** such requests, you should make the details clear.

It gave me a pause to choose between the two prepositions. Which one should be used? Does it have to do with the noun in the phrase? What about the following sentences?

> **In/for** event-related questions, you should mention the details.
>
> **In/for** questions about future events, you should write to me.

I find the last sentence stilted but can't put my finger on what's wrong with it. (Also, should it be "event-related" or "events-related"?)

Answer (score 1):

'In' sounds wrong to me. I'd definitely use for. But ... I speak British English and I quite often disagree with what Americans think is the better preposition.

Definitely 'event-related'. It is a compound adjective. Adjectives don't have singular or plural forms; they modify nouns which do.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use either of the two prepositions you mention. Instead, I'd use **with**.

Google Books NGram Viewer also [suggests](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20such%20requests%2Cfor%20such%20requests%2Cwith%20such%20requests&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20such%20requests%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20such%20requests%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20such%20requests%3B%2Cc0) that **with** is the most common preposition. (After that, the closest is *for*.)

[image: such requests]

If using just [*questions*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20questions%2C%20for%20questions%2C%20with%20questions&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20questions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20questions%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20questions%3B%2Cc0), **with** is still the most common, but the other two are essentially equal in usage:

[image]